# Devise destroy session doesn't destroy the session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session, devise

Really new to devise - it's very frustrating in all honesty...

My user session isn't being destroyed.

Here is the link in my navbar:

```
<li><%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></li>
```

devise.rb has the :delete method configured:

```
# The default HTTP method used to sign out a resource. Default is :delete.
  config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

Route is:

```
  destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)             sessions#destroy
```

Application controller says :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  private
      def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
        root_path
      end
```

I click my sign out link and my console shows :

```
Started GET "/users/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-18 12:00:26 -0500
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"sign_out"}
MONGODB (0.8ms) waittext_development['users'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('53515685963e6507ad00003e')}).limit(-1)
```

It doesn't seem to be finding an active session (I've clicked it a dozen times in frustration), but the problem is the page I land out - UsersController#show - is not the page I've told it to route to.  It should be the root_path which is users#index

So I was getting all these nil class errors on users#show because it was trying to render the default rails @user.name, etc. and @user isn't defined - I finally manually overrode the show action to simply render 'index' and I end up on my index page - BUT STILL - I'm seeing current_user.email printed here:

```
<% if user_signed_in? -%>
  <ul>
    <li><%= current_user.email %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'My info', edit_user_registration_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path %></li>
  </ul>
```

It is evaluating TRUE and I'm getting those three list items.

User *should not be signed in* because I just destroyed the session!

What the heck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i have implemented this so known to work:

```
  devise_scope :user do
    match "sign_out", :to => "sessions#destroy", via: [:delete]
  end

<%= link_to sign_out_path, :method => "DELETE" do %>

<% end%>
```

Comment: You got me at least one step forward - but I get this error: undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/users/sign_out":String - Googling now...

Comment: Ok so you get the error I was getting when you try :

<%= link_to "TEXT", path, :method => "DELETE" do %> <%end%>

You have to put the text between the do and end blocks in order to avoid the stringify_keys error.  Thank you - this fixed my problem

Answer (score 2):

You issue a `GET` request, not a `DELETE` (or even a POST with a set `_method` parameter to emulate a proper `DELETE`). As such, your request is routed to `UsersController#show` which listens to `GET /users/:id`.

The reason for that is, that a plain HTML link normally can only lead to GET requests. For anything else, you need a form. If you now pass the `:method` parameter to the `link_to` method in your view, Rails will generate some Javascript which captures the click on the link to generate a form and send the request that way. This will fail if the user has Javascript disabled, which seems to be the case here.

You should thus either ensure that all users (including you) have Javascript enabled or use something like `button_to` instead which will create a proper form in HTML which works without Javascript.

Comment: Your explanation helped me understand the issue - thank you.  I gave the correct answer to the person below because it mostly directly helped me fix my actual problem.